# How can we retain access to iOS keychain (or application groups) data after app transfer?

Tags: ios, keychain

My company bought some apps from their old publisher.
We are in the process of transferring them to our company as the new publisher.
One of the apps was (or would be) so large (~6gb), it was split into 3 parts - Stage A (~2gb), Stage B (~2gb), and Stage C (~2gb).
Since the apps were supposed to be a single application, it attempts to store the common settings into a shared keychain (in addition to settings per application via NSUserDefaults). Then, different stages can read the settings data from that shared keychain.

Since our apps will soon be transferred to the new company, we expect they will lose access to the old keychain since its team id will be changing.

Is there any way to maintain access to the data from the shared keychain after the apps have been transferred to our new company and then we upload later upgrade versions (with the new team id)?

One idea that I had was to create one more upgrade version with the old company and have that upgrade save the keychain data while it still had access to it. I thought perhaps it could save the data using iOS Application Groups - either with truly shared settings - or with a shared folder.

One potential problem I see with this approach is that it appears that application groups still depend on the team id:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19

p.s.I did read many of the other similar questions on this topic. The answers were not clear/consistent (you can maintain access to an old keychain - perhaps with Apple's help, or you can not). I'm also asking if my alternative idea is viable (and if is also usable after a team id change).